# PHPStan Extension: Dynamic Return Types and a Variadic Function Parameter

Tags: static-analysis, phpstan

Since PHPStan 1.6, it's possible to use [Conditional Return Types](https://phpstan.org/blog/phpstan-1-6-0-with-conditional-return-types#conditional-return-types), where I've been able to do things like:

```php
/**
 * @param string $x
 * @return ($x is literal-string ? literal-string : string)
 */
public function isNull($x)
{
}
```

This takes the form of `(<template param> is <union type> ? <union type> : <union type>)`.

While it's not possible to do more complicated conditions, it is possible to nest them (even if it gets a bit messy):

```php
/**
 * @param string $val
 * @param string $x
 * @param string $y
 * @return ($val is literal-string ? ($x is literal-string ? ($y is literal-string ? literal-string : string) : string) : string)
 */
public function between($val, $x, $y)
{
}
```

But I'm not sure how to handle a [Variadic Function Parameter](https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdocs-basics#variadic-functions), where the function can accept any number of values.

I'd like to return a `literal-string` when *all* values are a `literal-string`, otherwise return a `string`.

Maybe something like the following (which does not work):

```php
/**
 * @param string ...$x
 * @return ($x is array<literal-string> ? literal-string : string)
 */
function example(...$x) {
    return implode(', ', $x);
}
```

Is this a limitation of the current implementation in PHPStan, or am I missing something?

This relates to the PHPStan Doctrine Extension, and [Pull Request 324](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/pull/324#issuecomment-1112367950).

One option is to use a [Dynamic Return Type Extension](https://phpstan.org/developing-extensions/dynamic-return-type-extensions) ([which I might revert](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/pull/298/commits/2f6f12fa8fbfd8a702e933152878f59f08f29bc1)).

Comment: There may be a different/better solution, but Ondřej has started this as a [Feature Request](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/7234).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a `@template`, e.g.

```php
/**
 * @template T of string
 * @param T ...$x
 * @return (T is literal-string ? literal-string : string)
 */
public function countDistinct(...$x) {
}
```

But this does not work with Doctrine ORM 2.x, because it uses `($x)` not `(...$x)` for its arguments ([source](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/ab4844b82af9b18cdff20a4d14dc1aeb4ddd08da/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Expr.php#L263)), which [PR 9911](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/9911) fixes for 3.x.